# What is "ListViewport" and where is it documented?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

What is "ListViewport"? I saw that some users use this object. And I can only guess that it is a JavaScript object. But I have found no official description for it.

Any ideas?

Example from the stack forum: `ListViewport.instances[get('myId')].refreshList();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have seen `ListViewPort` in my [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/calling-apex-class-from-custom-button-and-then-refreshing-list-view) in the forum. I discovered `ListViewPort` while using *Inspect Element* on a Salesforce List View **Refresh button**, in Google Chrome. Hence, it is **not** a fail-safe approach.

`refreshList()` is a JavaScript function (written by Salesforce) to **refresh a *ListView***. I found this functionality useful because my Apex Class makes changes on a button click, and I wanted the changes to reflect **without** refreshing the whole page, i.e., **without** using `location.reload()`.

The `get` function (written by me) is get the URL parameter value.

E.g.
`ListViewport.instances[get('fcf')].refreshList()`

will execute
`ListViewport.instances['00B90000003oVDE'].refreshList()`

in one of my pages: https://ap1.salesforce.com/a00?fcf=00B90000003oVDE

Just in case you need it, here is the code to my `get()` function:

```
function get(name) { 
    if (name = (new RegExp('[?&]' + encodeURIComponent(name) + 
            '=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search)) { 
        return decodeURIComponent(name[1]); 
    } 
}
```

And here is the screenshot of the element inspection:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer bro! Very cool idea to use undocumented functionallity.

Comment: Plenty of undocumented but useful Salesforce functionality out there. We should never use them - they can stop working without notice. I use them in my DEV org only.